# What's wrong with my quick sort-only two digits' position are wrong?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, structure

My quick sort code is here:

```
template<typename T>
void quick_sort_recursive(T arr[], int start, int end) {
   if (start >= end) return;
   T pivot = arr[start];
   int left = start + 1, right = end;

   while (left < right) {        
        while (arr[right] >= pivot && left < right) right--;
        while (arr[left] < pivot && left < right) left++;
        std::swap(arr[left], arr[right]);
    }

    if (arr[right] <  arr[start])
        std::swap(arr[left], arr[start]);
    else
        right--;

    quick_sort_recursive(arr, start + 1, right - 1);
    quick_sort_recursive(arr, right + 1, end);
}

template<typename T>
void quick_sort(T arr[], int len) {
    quick_sort_recursive(arr, 0, len - 1);
}
```

---

The test array is :

```
int a[17] = {3,5,1,5,1,6,7,32,43,2,54,632,24,353,5,5435,35};
```

but, something strange happened. I got an output:

```
1
1
2
3
5
5
5
6
24
7
32
35
43
54
353
632
5435
```

So, why 7 and 24 are always wrong but others are correct?

Comment: What did you see when you debugged it?

Comment: First I use the last element as the pivot and the code can run correctly.But when I tried to change to the first element,I got into infinite loop,then I tracked the left and right,at last,there are one bug left,as you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursive calls

```
quick_sort_recursive(arr, start + 1, right - 1);
quick_sort_recursive(arr, right + 1, end);
```

omit two elements from the array. The element at position start and the element at position right. It seems you want to swap the pivot element into the middle between the two segments, so you should begin the first recursion with `start` and not `start + 1`.

Comment: Thank you so much. There used to be pounds of errors. I figured out to be one error left. 3Q.

Comment: More patterns may need to be tested to see if there are any other issues. The code is similar Hoare partition scheme, where the quick sort calls are quicksort(arr, start, pivot); quicksort(pivot+1, high). Does "end" point past the end of the array or to the last element? If it points to the last element then the names low and high would make more sense.